# Which form of cross-entropy loss is correct?

Tags: neural-networks, loss-functions, cross-entropy

For classification problems with more than two classes, I've seen these two forms of cross-entropy loss:

1. -$\sum_k y_k \log(a_k)$
2. -$\sum_k y_k \log(a_k) + (1-y_k) \log(1-a_k)$

Here $y_i$ are the true targets and $a_i$ are the activations at the last layer of some neural net, usually looking like probabilities.

As far as I know, 1. is the "correct" form of cross-entropy for two distributions. Is 2. somehow valid or equivalent?

Comment: if you actually wrote out what $k$ you were summing over, there would be no problem here :)

Answer (score 5):

(1) is used for multi-class problems. (2) is a specialized and equivalent version of it for two-class problems. The reason is, we usually have one output neuron in binary classification instead of two.

The summation in (1) is for number of classes. So, in (2), there should be no summation.

Here is some reference: https://ml-cheatsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/loss_functions.html#cross-entropy